# Cannot use generic model in mongoose: Argument of type 'x' is not assignable to parameter of type MongooseFilterQuery

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I am trying to pass a generic Mongoose model into a function as a parameter.

```js
import mongoose, { Document, Model, Schema } from 'mongoose';

interface User {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    favouriteAnimal: string;
}

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    favouriteAnimal: String,
});

const UserModel = mongoose.model<User & Document>('User', UserSchema);

function doSomething() {
    return UserModel.findOne({ user: 'john' }); // This is fine.
}

async function doSomethingGeneric<T extends User & Document>(model: Model<T>, key: keyof T) {
    const user = await model.findOne({ user: 'john' }); // Compiler errors on this line.
    return user![key];
}
```

This is the error output from the compiler:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ user: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MongooseFilterQuery<Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "toString" | "removeListener" | "off" | "update" | "invalidate" | "increment" | "model" | "$isDeleted" | "remove" | "save" | "__v" | "$isDefault" | "$session" | ... 47 more ... | "modelName">>>'.

Type '{ user: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ [P in keyof Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "toString" | "removeListener" | "off" | "update" | "invalidate" | "increment" | "model" | "$isDeleted" | "remove" | "save" | "__v" | "$isDefault" | "$session" | ... 47 more ... | "modelName">>]?: (P extends "_id" ? [...] extends [...] ? Condition<...> : Condition<...> : [...] e...'.

23    const user = await model.findOne({ user: 'john' });
```

The type of UserModel is `mongoose.Model<User & mongoose.Document, {}>`, so I would have expected the generic to satisfy the same type constraints as the non-generic method. Where am I going wrong?

Edit: I have [recreated the issue in the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?module=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBCCA7A5hCBnApgGjgbzgBEIBjAVxCyRjwFkIATLAGzwGVSALLEAQzgBfOADMoEEHADkiVOmxSA3AChlwGligi%20pLHACq2KAWVwzcJHyoAuOBhhR1KFebh8UWW0koAjTS-NtADcIckcYLABBJFA%20Flt7R1QVQVVSZHsDI04efjgAXgssAHc4HN4%20AAp8U3NLGzKHJxxas3dPOAA5X00W12DQ8KiY-njGpJQWwQBKFWV0pEzDTQZmFgKEZDRMLAA6RDWAHmXjADJiMkpqGAA%20SqkTqTwT8v5Z1RFyJFIYYGQ4RgQdgSLAwLhOSrTEyuKCgsJILIrJisXYidSMADySCw1Tg5CMtikACsIFwkFIhLM4AB6alwAAq4IwcGAzLR2N2ylSyj4GAAnt9RF8fn8EYDgVQwU4AOLUTTAUiHelwLAADwiSEYzJOcHOJAoVBodwOrFsq1YSpueAA1lg%20bZbXyICIGVCaq4Fpl8ZoNnxinxgPATSxUeisTjCN6oISSWSKTNFDS6QBhCRgYAsH2acRQZn-KXMljqPatOCwmDwvFGACEAG1HQBdFJAA) so you can see it directly.

Comment: Can you post please complete .ts file?

Comment: @Valijon this is a contrived example to demonstrate the issue; it is the entire .ts file. I’d not be able to share more without posting my actual code, but that would complicate the matter considerably as it includes a lot of stuff that is not at all relevant. However I am happy to clarify my question/example if there is something specific that is not clear?

Comment: Check if this solution resolve a problem `async function doSomethingGeneric<T extends User & Document>(model: mongoose.Model<T>, key: keyof T, query: any) { const user = await model.findOne(query); return user![key];}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been confirmed to be a Typescript bug: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/39358

A possible workaround is to manually cast the query object to the right type:

```
async function doSomethingGeneric<T extends User & Document>(model: Model<T>, key: keyof T) {
    const user = await model.findOne({ user: 'john' } as FilterQuery<T>);
    return user![key];                    /* add this ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
}
```